# Question on Calibrated Structured Prediction (Kuleshov, 2015)

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, calibration

I have several questions regarding equation (2) from the paper: [Calibrated Structured Prediction (Kuleshov, 2015)](https://papers.nips.cc/paper_files/paper/2015/file/52d2752b150f9c35ccb6869cbf074e48-Paper.pdf). I believe most of my questions stem from not understanding the quantity: $T(x)=\mathbb{E}[y|F(x)]$ defined as "the true probability $y=1$ given that $x$ received a forecast $F(x)$.

Q1: How would you write "$y-T(x)$ has expectation 0 conditioned on $F(x)$"?

$$ \mathbb{E}[y-T(x)|F(x)] =0$$ or $$\mathbb{E}[(y-T(x))|F(x)]=0$$

Q2: Why is this statement true: "$y-T(x)$ has expectation 0 conditioned on $F(x)$"? And does the validity of this statement depend on having a "good" forecaster, $F(x)$?

Q3: How is $T$ used to decompose the $l_2$ prediction loss? The authors decompose it into...

$$\mathbb{E}[(y-F(x))^2] = \mathbb{E}[(y-T(x))^2]+\mathbb{E}[(T(x)-F(x))^2]$$

But starting from the equation below, I'm not sure where to go...

$$\mathbb{E}[(y-F(x))^2] = \mathbb{E}[y^2-2\cdot y \cdot  F(x) + F(x)^2]$$

I have tried to work backwards by also expanding the authors' original equation to ...
$$\mathbb{E}[y^2-2 \cdot y \cdot T(x) + T(x)^2 + T(x)^2 -2 \cdot F(x) \cdot T(x) + F(x)^2]$$
then setting that equation to the expanded form of $\mathbb{E}[(y-F(x))^2]$:
$$\mathbb{E}[y^2-2 \cdot y \cdot T(x) + 2 \cdot T(x)^2 -2 \cdot F(x) \cdot T(x) + F(x)^2] = \mathbb{E}[y^2-2\cdot y \cdot  F(x) + F(x)^2]$$
$$\mathbb{E}[-2 \cdot y \cdot T(x) + 2 \cdot T(x)^2 -2 \cdot F(x) \cdot T(x)] = \mathbb{E}[-2\cdot y \cdot  F(x)]$$
$$\mathbb{E}[- y \cdot T(x) + T(x)^2 - F(x) \cdot T(x)] = \mathbb{E}[- y \cdot  F(x)]$$

But at this point, I am stuck. I do not see how to leverage "$y−T(x)$
has expectation 0 conditioned on $F(x)$" to understand or simplify the equation further.

Thank you for reading! Any and all guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is valid (so please help if you can explain), but if I decide to do the following:

$$ \mathbb{E}[(y-F(x))^2] = \mathbb{E}[(y-T(x)+T(x)-F(x))^2] $$
 
so I can complete the square:

$$\mathbb{E}[(y-F(x))^2] = \mathbb{E}[(y-T(x))^2 + 2(y-T(x))(T(x)-F(x))+ (T(x)-F(x))^2]$$

then use the author's assertion that $\mathbb{E}[y-T(x)|F(x)]=0$ (which I still don't understand) and acknowledge $T(x)-F(x)$ is a constant, then the middle term becomes zero and I get the author's equation (2):

$$\mathbb{E}[(y-F(x))^2] = \mathbb{E}[(y-T(x))^2]+ \mathbb{E}[(T(x)-F(x))^2] 
$$

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Might you want to post that as an edit to your original question or (perhaps) as a self-answer?